# Self Learning, react recursion, maximum call stack size

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Dialog Component

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog'
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions'
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent'
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText'
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle'

export default function ResearchDialog(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={props.dialog}
        onClose={props.off}
        aria-labelledby='alert-dialog-title'
        aria-describedby='alert-dialog-description'
      >
        <DialogTitle id='alert-dialog-title'>
          {"Use Google's location service?"}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id='alert-dialog-description'>
            Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending
            anonymous location data to Google, even when no apps are running.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={props.off}>Disagree</Button>
          <Button onClick={props.off} autoFocus>
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Dropdown Menu Component

```
import React from 'react'
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search'
import PictureAsPdfIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PictureAsPdfOutlined'
import { Menu, MenuItem, ListItemIcon } from '@material-ui/core'

export default function DropdownMenu(props) {
  return (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={props.anchor}
      open={props.open}
      onClose={props.off}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'left'
      }}
      transformOrigin={{
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'right'
      }}
      MenuListProps={{
        'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button'
      }}
    >
      <MenuItem onClick={props.onDialog}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <SearchIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        {'Search Again'}
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={props.off}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <PictureAsPdfIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        {'Download as PDF'}
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  )
}
```

Parent Page

```
import {
  Grid,
  Card,
  Typography,
  IconButton,
} from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import MoreVertIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles'
import DropdownMenu from './DropdownMenu'
import ResearchDialog from './ResearchDialog'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  moreIconButton: {
    borderRadius: '11px',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(118, 128, 163, 0.3)'
    }
  }
})

function SearchHistorys(props) {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const [anchor, setAnchor] = useState(false)
  const open = Boolean(anchor)
  const handleAnchorOpen = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation()
    setAnchor(event.currentTarget)
  }
  const handleAnchorClose = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation()
    setAnchor(null)
  }

  const [dialog, setDialog] = useState(false);

  const handleDialogOpen = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation()
    setDialog(true);
  };

  const handleDialogClose = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation()
    setAnchor(null)
    setDialog(false);
  };

  console.log("rerender")

  return (
    <Card
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(137,150,175,.0627451)',
        marginTop: '2vh',
        padding: '2vh',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        boxShadow: 'none'
      }}
    >
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={10}>
          <Typography color='textPrimary' variant='h5'>
            {props.party.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography color='textSecondary' variant='caption'>
            Search Matches: {props.party.searchMatch}
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          item
          xs={1}
          style={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            display: 'flex'
          }}
        >
          <Typography color='textSecondary'>
            {props.party.createdDate}
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          item
          xs={1}
          style={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            display: 'flex'
          }}
        >
          <IconButton
            className={classes.moreIconButton}
            aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
            aria-haspopup={'true'}
            aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
            onClick={handleAnchorOpen}
          >
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Grid>
        <DropdownMenu anchor={anchor} open={open} off={handleAnchorClose} onDialog={handleDialogOpen} />
        <ResearchDialog dialog={dialog} off={handleDialogClose}/>
      </Grid>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default SearchHistorys
```

I would like to ask any reason why, when i close my dialog with handleDialogClose(). My console show "TrapFocus.js:214 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded."

In my SearchHistorys page, i have one drop down button to turn on DropdownMenu component, in the Dropdown Menu there is a button to trigger search again function will pop a dialog for user to confirm if they would like to search again.

This issue happen when I try to close the dialog.

I would like to know why this happen. Not sure which part causing the issue. If direct turn on and off Dialog without integrate with DropdownMenu it will not throw error.

**Update, i found not only close the dialog. When i alt + tab to other application and tab back, it will throw same error. Seems like lost focus the issue will happen ?

Before close dialog.
[Close Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oryRH.png)

Closed Dialog
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbscm.png)

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] and isolate the problem?

Comment: Hi @jabba, i try to clean my code, could you please check again.

Comment: I've run into this error before when using multiple React apps with MUI on a single page., they can get into a state where they fight for focus. I used the `disableEnforceFocus` option ([documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/#Modal-prop-disableEnforceFocus)) on the dialog components to avoid that. (That may/may not be the best solution for you, but hopefully it's helpful info)

Comment: Here's a sandbox, I'm not sure if it's working, though. Hope this helps someone who has the time to answer the question, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2ga7om?file=src%2FApp.js